# How to create a swipeable week-hours view calendar in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, calendar, ionic4, angular-calendar

I am using this tutorial to create week-hours view calendar Ionic Calendar

https://devdactic.com/ionic-calendar-angular-calendar/

But i want to make this calendar swipeable like Google Calendar in Android.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, Actually we tried using ion-slides but it gives a performance issues.

Comment: performance is the biggest problem i face - thanks